# The gameOver sound plays non stop

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, sprite-kit

The gameOver sound plays non stop when the image leaves the screen (the game is supposed to end). This shows that the gameOver method continues to be called by the update method even if the game is over and the menu is shown. I hope you understand what is going on. What can I do to stop this?

Edit: after adding `&& !gameEnds` (see the update method below), the `gameOver` method is called twice, I wonder why out of all the numbers, it is called two times.

```
-(void)gameOver
{
    self.gameEnds = YES;

    // Play the gameOver sound
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"gameOver.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];

    [mainLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"Board" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0f]];
    }];

    [mainLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"Time" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:1.0f]];
    }];

    // showing the menu
    [menu show];
}
```

This method counts the number of taps (self.counter increments when the user taps the screen)

```
-(void)callNextImage: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    self.counter++;
}
```

gameOver method should be called when the image leaves the screen and the number of taps is less than 4, and this method seems to relevant for this

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (self.counter < 4
        && (image.position.y > self.frame.size.height + 75.5f) && !gameEnds) {
        [self gameOver];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: @matt: I did, it shows that the gameOver method is called over and over

Comment: Excellent! But it also shows you _who is calling_ the `gameOver` method over and over. Thus, you can readily discover the cause of the problem.

Comment: @matt: do you have any suggestions?, I tried placing the method outside update method but its not called, so it is only called when inside the update method.

Comment: You have a condition here: `(self.counter < 4 && (image.position.y > self.frame.size.height + 75.5f))`. You are calling `gameOver` only if that condition is true. Modify the condition (or the environment that it tests) in such a way that the condition is _not_ true after `gameOver` is called.

Comment: Or, in your `gameOver` implementation, pause the scene - after all, the game is over, is it not? Now `update:` won't be called any more. But there might be other reasons why you don't want to do that.

Comment: @matt: I used a boolean, set it to YES when the game starts, and checked if its true with the above conditions (as you suggested), then set it to NO after calling the gameOver method. Now, the gameOver method is not called over and over but rather called twice. I checked with the breakpoints.I wonder why out of all the the numbers, it is called two times.

Comment: Well, I can't see your new code, so I don't know. It looks like you already have a boolean (`gameEnds`) which you are already setting to YES is `gameOver`. So surely all you have to do is add `&& !gameEnds` to your existing condition.

Comment: @matt: I edited the question, take a look at it

Comment: I don't know why that is. But just add a condition to the start of `gameOver`: `if (self.gameEnds) return;`. Now, even if `gameOver` is called twice, it won't matter because the thing that it does will be done only once. :)

Comment: Probably rhe reason it is still being called more than once is because you need to set the Boolean first, ourside of the async call, rather than after the call, so follow up calls to the method can't face the setting of the Boolean. While I didn't emphasise it explicitly in my answer, my answer did from the beginning suggest you set the Boolean first. :)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious approach would be to pause the scene. Thus, `gameOver` would include this line:

```
self.paused = true
```

This will stop `update:` from being called any longer. You can only do that if you have no more animations to be performed, but since the game is over, perhaps that is in fact the case.

If that approach is unacceptable, then you need to modify the condition that you are testing in `update:` to see whether you should call `gameOver` in such a way that if it is true on one pass it is not also true on the next pass and the next and the next and the next... For example you could raise a Bool flag (property) in `gameOver` and test it in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this method is being called continually, and is still being called once the game is back at the menu, but I bet that isn't the case. Your method to play the sound is being called asynchronously, and you've simply created a finite but very large number of calls to the method by coming to the game over method before every frame is rendered, and there are multiple frames that meet your "game over" criteria before you've actually exited the game. If you waited long enough at the menu after the game, eventually all the queued sounds would play and it would stop.

You just need a way to ensure the method to play the sound only gets called once. This could be as simple as having a Boolean property gameIsOver. If it is not YES, you set it to yes and then make the call to the method that plays the sound. Otherwise, return.

Comment: I edited the the code (the question), I `&& !gameEnds` to the conditions in the update method. But now the `gameOver` method is called twice.

Comment: Your point is true, if I remove `&& !gameEnds` from the conditions, the `gameOver` method gets called once the sound is played multiple times. I have tried the boolean, it doesn't help. calling `return` after checking the condition does not help as well.